# IISNode not picking up NODE_ENV

Tags: iisnode

I have a NodeJS apps hosted on a server behind IISNode. I have set the NODE_ENV in the **web.config**

```
<iisnode node_env="staging" />
```

and in the **iisnode.yml**

```
node_env: staging
```

but my application does not seem to pick it up. It picks up the values that I had initially set when I set up the server. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Node was picking up the environment variable I had set rather than the values in the config. I removed the environment variable and boom - it started picking up the values in the config.